# convert csv columns to dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file with the following data.

```
Column-1 Column-2 Column-3
bob      sweet    4
alice    uber     4.5
bob      uber     4
alice    sweet    4.5
razi     fav      2.5
razi     uber     3.5
bob      fav      4
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary as shown,

```
   A={'bob':{'sweet':'4', 'uber':'4', 'fav':'4'}, 
      'alice':{'uber':'4.5', 'sweet':'4.5'}, 
      'razi':{'fav':'2.5', 'uber':'3.5'}}
```

in python

For that i am willing to do like this..convert the csv to list like this and then get my output. I am unable to do so, coz keys are repeated as shown.

```
   A={'bob':['sweet','4'], 
      'alice':['uber','4.5'], 
      'bob':['uber','4'], 
      'alice':['sweet','4.5'], 
      'razi':['fav','2.5'], 
      'razi':['uber','3.5'], 
      'bob':['fav','4']}
```

Can any one suggest a way to solve problem?

Comment: you definitely don't have your input as you have posted, you cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: no padriac, my data has many such values. Its possible.

Comment: copy/paste your first example and print it in a shell

Comment: @user3905334 Not it isn't. In you first dictionary, you have _several_ items with the _same_ key (not mentioning `razi` unquoted).

Comment: @user3905334: Paste `A` into Python and only one of each key-value pair is preserved. Are you certain you don't have a list or other sequence of key-value pairs instead?

Comment: One min..i will post my exact problem..

Comment: To extend on what PadraicCunningham, SylvainLeroux and MartijnPieters say, dictionaries can be seen as [Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). And as each identical key has the same hash, the values will fall into the same bucket. So duplicate keys are not possible (one will overwrite the other). Also, as a side-effect, basic hash tables have no deterministic ordering.

Comment: Maybe are you using some kind of [mutlidict](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/datastructures/) ? This is _not_ part of core Python though; and the syntax does not match.

Comment: ... now that you have posted your original problem, I am even more curious about how you got duplicate keys into a dict. This is like dividing by zero... just not possible... What are you not telling us? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming* you don't have any space in your datas, and all your actual data rows have exactly 3 fields:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) # <- in a real application,
                                           # should be set application-wide
                                           # from a config file

logger = logging.getLogger("CSV import")

result = {}
nlines = 0
ok = 0
warnings = 0
with open("my_file.csv") as f:
    f.readline() # Skip header. Assuming only one line of heading

    for row in (line.split() for line in f):
        nlines += 1
        try:
            k1,k2, val = row
            result.setdefault(k1,{})[k2] = val
            ok += 1
        except ValueError:
            logger.warning("Format mismatch: %s", row)
            warnings += 1
            # what to do next?

logger.info("%d lines read. %d imported. %d warnings",nlines,ok,warnings)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Given your sample data file, this produces:

```
INFO:CSV import:7 lines read. 7 imported. 0 warnings
{'alice': {'sweet': '4.5', 'uber': '4.5'},
 'bob': {'fav': '4', 'sweet': '4', 'uber': '4'},
 'razi': {'fav': '2.5', 'uber': '3.5'}}
```

The *trick* here is to use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to access to outer dictionary. It will either return the value if the key was already present -- or a new dictionary if this is the first time we encounter that key. After that, this is simply a matter of adding the value to the inner dictionary as usual.

Comment: I was just about to post something but using a `defaultdict`, which made the few lines a bit more concise.

Comment: @exhuma I was a big user of `defaultdict` myself. But now, I prefer using `setdefault` instead when you only needs default _during the construction_ of the dictionary. That prevents the default value to pop out unexpected later in the program.

Comment: That's a very good point!

Comment: What is the "data" here?
I am having all the above in a csv file, so should i read it and is that what "data" means?
Because, its giving the follwoing error: 

for k1, k2, val in (row.split() for row in f):
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @user3905334 That's your filename. See [the official docs of `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @user3905334 Fixed to be ... hum ... "less confusing"

Comment: its giving the follwoing error: for k1, k2, val in (row.split() for row in f): ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @user3905334 That probably means that your file does not perfectly correspond to the examples you have given us, and that some line has not enough fields.

Comment: @user3905334 Not given _your sample input_. You probably have "empty lines" or so? Please edit your question to show a _short but significant_ example of your actual data.

Comment: I dont have any empty lines, i ran the code with the data i have given you only, its still giving me the same error !! :(
"for k1, k2, val in (row.split() for row in f):
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack"

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Silently skipping errors? I would at *least* log them on a `DEBUG` level. This is an amazing source for weird bugs down the road ;) ... The `debug` line could even include the offending value (or line number).

Comment: Guys, i created a csv file with the data (of 7 rows and 3 columns) that i gave you..i used that file only, but now again its showing this  error--k1,k2, val = row
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

I am not trying with my original data now, i am using the data that i posted here only !

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Is there a reason you use `if not len(row)` instead of `if not row`?

Comment: @user3905334 To be blunt: Given your question (verbatim), Sylvain's answer *is* correct! If it does not work for you, then your question is wrong. So either update your question, or accept Sylvain's answer! **BUT** again: to give you the benefit of the doubt, give us a hexdump of the first few lines of the file. Just in case the spaces are no spaces...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59937/discussion-on-answer-by-sylvain-leroux-convert-csv-columns-to-dictionary-in-pyth).